# Muti table inheritance in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, orm

In my rails app, i have a `CASE` domain entity which serves as the logical super class of case-specific domain models (i.e. `CASEA`, `CASEB`, `CASEC`) like so:

```
               +--------+
               |  CASE  |
               +--------+
                    ^
                    |
      +-------------+-------------+
      |             |             |
  +-------+     +-------+     +-------+
  | CASEA |     | CASEB |     | CASEC |
  +-------+     +-------+     +-------+
```

The idea is to have one domain model with properties that are common to all cases, and one domain model per specific case type, that encapsulates the properties specific to that case.

I need to implement a muti-table inheritance design using a **bidirectional** one-to-one relationship whereby each specific case instance (`CASEX`) must reference one and only one case instance (`CASE`). Inversely, each `CASE` instance should reference one and only one case specific instance (`CASEX`). Note that each specific case is a different domain model class. Moreover, i would like **CASE** to be the owner of the relationship, in order saves, updates and deletes to be cascaded to the other end like so:

```
case = Case.new
case.case_info = CaseX.new
case.save!
# both case and CaseX are validated and saved
```

What would be the best approach to implement this relationship using active record?

Comment: Have you ruled out using either STI or polymorphism for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i actually want is some kind of a multiple table inheritance. Looking around i came up with this article, explaining how to implement a solution using polymorphic relations. It is exactly what we want to achieve.

http://mediumexposure.com/multiple-table-inheritance-active-record/

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing sounds like a strong use-case for single-table inheritance (STI).  This means you literally have one table with a superset of all attributes across the 3 specific cases (A, B, C) and rails knows to pull the right ones.

One blog post that describes this well is here:

http://blog.eizesus.com/2009/10/sti-best-practices-in-rails/

It depends though - the 'bad example' in the above link is bad because of the lack of overlap between attributes.  If you have a relatively large amount of overlap, STI may be a win for you.

If you are set on going with separate tables, you're looking at a has_many/belongs_to relationship between your case and sub-case models.  You probably want a custom validation method on the Case object to ensure that only one of the specific case types is present.

Comment: I don't think that STI will work in my case. The fact is that although  i have included 3 subtypes in my example, in the production there may be much more. Considering that each subtype could have any number of properties (columns), the supertable you refer to could grow to a unmaintainable size in terms of the number of columns. To complicate things further, we also have sub-hierarchies present in some of the subtypes.